# rfkill unblock bluetooth is timing out

Tags: linux, bluetooth

I'm creating a Bluetooth script that controls every aspect of the Bluetooth experience with headphones.

As part of this I want to reset the Bluetooth adapter. I'm using:

```
rfkill block bluetooth
rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

This should toggle and it does work, just not every time. There is also no pattern to when it doesn't work. Sometimes (and often about 60% of the time) it times out.

Checking the logs reveal:

GOOD CASE :

```
Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Manufacturer: Atheros Communications
SerialNumber: Alaska Day 2006
Adapter /org/bluez/4100/hci0 has been enabled
Endpoint registered: sender=:1.25 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Endpoint registered: sender=:1.25 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Endpoint registered: sender=:1.25 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Endpoint registered: sender=:1.25 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
```

BAD CASE (WHEN IT TIMES OUT) :

```
Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Manufacturer: Atheros Communications
SerialNumber: Alaska Day 2006
Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout
Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1001 tx timeout
```

Is there some way I can increase this timeout, failing that using BASH, check for the timeout, and in a loop - just keep retrying till it works - because eventually it does, if the adapter is completely reset again using rfkill block.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you are doing this with rfkill? Try resetting device or service.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a sleep statement between the 2 `rfkill` commands.

```
rfkill block bluetooth
sleep 5
rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

This is in seconds, adjust and see if it helps.

Comment: sleep is good for when it's scripted, but the unblock operation still times out.